# Create tables in different directories MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, database

I am attempting use MySQL to create two tables on separate drives so I can do some bench marking.  I found [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html) on the `Data Directory` command which seems to do exactly what I need, but it is not working for me.  Here is what I get:

```
mysql> create database test;  
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)  

mysql> use test;  
Database changed  
mysql> show variables like 'innodb_file_per_table';  
+-----------------------+-------+  
| Variable_name         | Value |  
+-----------------------+-------+  
| innodb_file_per_table | ON    |  
+-----------------------+-------+   
1 row in set (0.00 sec)  

mysql> create table t1 (id int primary key, name text) data directory = '/media/ssd';  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

However the table file is made in the default `/var/lib/mysql/test` and `/media/ssd` remains empty.

```
$ sudo ls /var/lib/mysql/test  
db.opt  t1.frm  t1.ibd  
$ ls -l /media/ssd  
total 0
```

I have also tried other locations like `/home` and I get the same result so I don't believe it is a drive mounting issue.  I also set the `/media/ssd` permissions to 777.

Any ideas why it is creating the table in the default location?

If need be can I just move the `.idb` file to my desired location and put a `.isl` in it's place?

Comment: if  --skip-symbolic-links at startup enabled ? Then its not work.
 https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-table/#data-directoryindex-directory

Comment: Works fine for me with 5.6.21.

Comment: Let the mysql user own the directory instead of setting it to 777.